# How to install llvm as c/c++ library?

Tags: c++, c, llvm, clang++, lib

I'm trying to compile a code snippet that uses llvm as c++ library but I'm getting errors such as the compiler could not find header files.

The compiler commands I used are:

```
clang++ file.cpp -o reader `llvm-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags --system-libs`
```

and

```
clang++ file.cpp -o reader `llvm-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags --system-libs` -v -fno-exceptions
```

I've also tried to specify the include directory:

```
clang++ parser.cpp -o reader `llvm-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags --system-libs` -v -fno-exceptions -I$(llvm-config –includedir)
```

and with specifying manually the path to the lib.
However, nothing was successful.
It seems that I should install llvm as library apart from it being installed as a tool - but I can't find any reasonable description on how to do it.

If I'm right and it should be somehow installed, I would appreciate your help for explaining how to do that. If it shouldn't and you can see any other issue that is preventing me from compiling the code, I would appreciate your help in that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you checked what `llvm-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags --system-libs` returns? Please show the code that is producing the error and the exact error messages

Comment: As I'm new to llvm usage, I've tried to compile the code from the answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195204/how-to-parse-llvm-ir-line-by-line) "as-is".
And I'm getting the next error: "file.cpp:7:10: fatal error: 'llvm/Bitcode/ReaderWriter.h' file not found"

Comment: @AlanBirtles, the command mentioned returned:
-I/<path/to>/lib/llvm-10/include -std=c++14   -fno-exceptions -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-L/<path/to>/lib/llvm-10/lib 
-lLLVM-10

Comment: But --system-libs is empty